# What happened to my primary keys?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I'm using rails 2.3.4

When I execute rake db:test:prepare the id field created is not a primary key and auto-incremented.

When I look at the development db no problem with the primary keys.

Using MySQL.

Edit: It looks like my schema.rb file was changed :id => false should be true. What generates this file? DB Migrations?

[EDIT] What is the actual mechanics for generating the schema.rb file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you perform rake tasks, the tasks are executed to the default environment if no environment is specified.

You probably have different schema versions between your test and development databases.

```
rake db:reset #drops and created the database for current environment
rake db:reset:all #drops and creates database for all environments
rake db:migrate #migrates the schema for the current environment
rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test #migrates the schema for the test environment
```

If I'm not wrong (as I remember right now)

```
rake db:migrate #applies the migrations and dumps the schema to db/schema.rb file
rake db:schema:dump #dumps the actual state of your current environment schema into db/schema.rb file
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey I looked at this question yesterday and see nobody has answered yet so I'll try to help, to be honest I don't know exactly why that is happening mainly as I've not really used the 'prepare' task. When running the migrations against an empty database the schema.rb gets created.

I normally run db:test:clone whenever changes have been made to that scheme, this ensures your test database is always in-line with your current environments. Maybe try dropping the DB and recreating it from your migrations, then run the clone. After this does the schema still show :id => false? If so can you post up your migration that is creating the table in question.

Comment: But when you use rspec it uses db:test:prepare. The real question is how the scema.rb got changed?

Comment: True. So was once OK? If you roll back your dev. database to version 0 then back up again what is it set to in the schema? Does it still have :id => false. Has this only happened on one table or all of them?

Comment: No primary keys in development. I believe this comes from schema.rb. What generates a new schema.rb?

Comment: Use SQL to drop your database. (Backup first if you want your data). Then delete (also backup for comparision maybe) your scheme.rb then run your migrations. You will then have a new schema.rb.

Comment: You'll need to create the DB again before running the migrations, rake db:create will do that.

Answer (score 1):

If you use 'reset' then 'db:test:prepare' you'll likely get the result you'r looking fore. 
Like so:

```
rake db:reset
rake db:test:prepare
```

This will:

- recreate the dev database based on your latest migrations
- recreate the schema.rb file based on the migrations/dev database
- recreate the test database based on the schema.rb file.